# Dead npc won't respawn

Tags: terraria

I found my mechanic in a dungeon and she died by angry bones. Now she won't respawn. I don't know if it was too late but i quickly built a house. I don't know if she'll respawn. Please tell me if she will.

Answer (score 1):

She will respawn, specifically - arrive on the next morning. Usually that's the case, though sometimes it could take a day or two. The prerequisite for her respawn is a free hosing available.

Answer (score -2):

If you did talk to her or flag a house for her, she probably won't respawn. Good luck. Unless you want some wiring and stuff and the achievement for gaining all villagers, she is not needed.